# Python - Acessar uma função acima fora de uma classe

Tags: python, python-kivy

Olá, pessoal!
Uma pergunta em relação à Python.

Eu tenho uma estrutura mais ou menos assim:

```
class Tela(FloatLayout):
   def exemplo(self):
      print("teste")

   class botao(Button):
      ?????
```

Explicando: É uma tela que tem uma função e uma classe. Eu queria saber como faço para acessar a função que está na classe "Tela" dentro da classe "botao". 
Achei que pudesse ser algo do tipo: variavel = Tela.exemplo() ou root.exemplo(), mas nada disso deu certo. Como é feito isso?

Comment: A classe botão está definida dentro da classe tela? Se sim, por quê?

Comment: Olá Anderson! Então, como sou iniciante, na verdade eu fiz isso mais por uma questão de ficar organizado. :)

Answer (score 1):

Não há qualquer ganho ou motivo para definir classes dentro de classes em Python. (Ok, na verdade há um motivo bem secundário: você pode querer usar suas classes como namespaces para manter valores)

Mas nesse caso, você não ganha nada. O que a sua "Tela" vai precisar ter são instâncias de "Botao" as instâncias você cria quando criar sua instância de "Tela" - mas repito: não há nenhum ganho, nenhum benefício, nada, nada de se definir uma classe dentro da outra.  Por outro lado, ao fazer isso você vai trabalhar na contramão da linguagem, e várias coisas por baixo do capô que estão lá para te ajudar começam a trabalhar contra. 
Não poder, de dentro da classe aninhada, acessar a classe acima é só uma dessas coisas.

Então, o que você deve fazer? Manter atributos dentro das suas classes que as conectem com os objetos relacionados - por exemplo: um botão vai precisar saber em que tela está - então ele deve receber essa informação quando for criado.

Olha como fica simples:

```
class Botao:
   def __init__(self, tela):
       self.tela = tela
       ...
   def acao(self):
       self.tela.acao_global()

class Tela:
   def __init__(self):
        self.botao_ok = Botao(self)
        self.botao_cancela = Botao(self)

   def acao_global(self):
       # chamada quando o método "acao" de qualquer botao é executado
```

Comment: Puxa vida!! Excelente explicação, @jsbueno, agradeço a mini aula, ehehe!

Entendi o que você quis dizer. 
Na verdade tive uma base legal do Python, mas como sou iniciante, ainda derrapo em algumas coisas que são conceituais! Mas obrigado mesmo!!
Abraço!

Comment: é - desculpa se eu insisti tanto na idéia de não usar classes aninhadas - achoque dá para entender quando falo a primeira vez. Mas é que já peguei gente que insiste em fazer isso, e quando escrevo algo aqui, sempre escrevo pensando que mais gente, além de quem fez a pergunta original, vai ler.

Comment: Não, com certeza @jsbueno! Cara, eu sempre tenho pra mim que programação você tem que ter sempre a cabeça aberta e aprender o máximo o que as outras pessoas que falam. Eu até me acostumei a pensar dessa forma na programação "aninhada". Mas gostei muito do que você aconselhou! Preciso só mudar minha forma de pensar na hora da programação, mas gostei muito! Agradeço!